# How to display only pre-defined array index value in the autocomple?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My autocomplete works by fetching data from database as the suggestions in the list. But I did little modification on it. Instead of showing string value, I want to show in array form.

Please refer to this fiddle for the javascript I used:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLfpsn4y/

below is my php:

```
$my_data='$_GET["data"]';// this is the data user keys in
$sql="SELECT place,lat FROM loc_coordinate WHERE place LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY place";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$test=array();
if ($result) {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['place']." \n";//this is the name of the place shown in the autocomplete list
    }
}
```

This displays like this:

[image: existing autocomplete result]

But I want to change it as shown below(in array form)

```
echo $row['place'].">".$row['lat']." \n ".//show two items in the array
```

[image: Result of autocomplete]

And now, when user selects any of the item from the autocomplete list, I want only `$row['lat']` to be selected.

But It selects both as a single string like this:

[image: Desired autocomplete result]

How to make it display just 2.993518 //maybe can access it like `$arrayName[1]`

I believe changes needed to be done in the javascript file.

Comment: FYI, this script is very insecure and completely susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: @Pitchinnate I'm aware of that...now I just want to get the function right first

Comment: "_I believe changes needed to be done in the javascript file_". Please provide the related javascript code.

Comment: @It's in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aLfpsn4y/1/